# What word means 'to submit a post' / 'bring to public notice online'?

Tags: synonyms

I dictionary.com'd the definition of the word 'post' and it has nothing to do which submitting a typed message to the Internet. One of the latter definitions shown on dictionary.com was 'to bring to public notice'. I then tried to look up synonyms of the word 'post' and it just gave synonyms of the word 'pole' and no word which has to do with 'bringing to public notice'. Most websites also use the word 'submit' meaning to 'submit the message' but dictionary.com and most people's definition of this word is 'to give over / yield to the power of another'.

I'm creating an app and I need a word each means 'let everyone on the app see this message' and I don't want to use the word 'post'. Is there any other word out there whos main definition is 'to bring to public notice' / 'to bring to public notice online'?

Comment: to display an announcement online.

Comment: @Josh61 right, is there a word which means to 'display an announcement online'?

Comment: How about "present"?

Comment: The appropriate word is ***post***. See Definition 2.2 of [Oxford Dictionaries Online](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/post?q=post): *Submit (a message, link, image, etc.) to an online location, such as a blog, social media website, or forum: the list was promptly posted all over the Internet.*

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is turns on OP's inexplicable wish to avoid the standard term ***post***

Answer (score 3, accepted):

*Publish* is a good alternative to *post*, in your context.  It is used frequently by Content Management Systems to describe uploading content to the internet.

Answer (score 2):

I suppose I may be looking too deep, but the type of app is important to take into account. For example, a chat room and a forum are going to have different words for "Send my message to the others." I personally like the *Publish* that is mentioned by @Jim V, especially if it is an article/forum setting.

Some other options that could be considered: *Announce*, *Dispatch*, or *Admit*.

The style of app I strongly feel will guide your decision, but hopefully even the bad ideas for words may get you thinking of what options you have.